# Typoscript: page id in additional headers

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In Typo3, if the language is changed I redirect to a different domain. Now, I want to keep the page ID.

So I try it:

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 0]
  config.additionalHeaders = HTTP/1.1 301 Permanent Redirect | Location: http://www.example.com/index.php?id={page:uid}
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
  config.additionalHeaders = HTTP/1.1 301 Permanent Redirect | Location: http://www.example.co.uk/index.php?id={page:uid}
[globalVar = GP:L = 4]
  config.additionalHeaders = HTTP/1.1 301 Permanent Redirect | Location: http://www.example.de/index.php?id={page:uid}
[global]
```

But {page:uid} is not replaced in the redirect. {TSFE:id} also does not work.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

additionalHeaders does not have stdWrap. but there is a patch for that

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/23494

Comment: Thank you! Is there another solution without a patch?